# How to parameterize image version when passing yaml for container creation

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to pass image version from a varibale/config when passing a manifest .yaml to kubectl command

Example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:${IMAGE_VERSION}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
         limits:
           cpu: "1.2"
           memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Use case is to launch specific image version which is set at kubernetes level, and that the variable is resolved by kubernetes itself at server side.

Thanks and Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

k8s manifest files are static yaml/json.

If you would like to template the manifests (and manage multiple resources in a bundle-like fashion), I strongly recommend you to have a look at [Helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm)

I've recently created [a Workshop which focuses precisely on the "Templating" features of Helm](https://github.com/cloud-native-singapore/helm-workshop#templating-and-release-management).

Helm does a lot more than just templating, it is built as a full fledged package manager for Kubernetes applications (think Apt/Yum/Homebrew).

If you want to handle everything client side, have a look at https://github.com/errordeveloper/kubegen

Although, at some point, you will need the other features of Helm and a migration will be needed when that time comes - I recommend biting the bullet and going for Helm straight up.

Comment: another option is to use the `kubectl set` command to set the image tag on an existing deployment (which can be part of a CI/CD pipeline to trigger a rolling update) - however, the question here was to specifically template manifests.

Comment: Hypothetical use-case to make it more clear. 
Say, I have a notebooklauncher service launching zeppelin notebook containers

Now, in the launcher service... not hard-coding the zeppelin image version to be launched or tag to 'latest' 
Now, if there was a way to dynamically pump in the zeppelin.image.version using a ConfigMap.... it would have nailed.

I tried this approach....obviously did not work.
Again, the image version has to be detected by the server side of kube i.e. in api-server when reading/parsing yaml....
Helm or other bash templaters do this at client side.

Comment: Instead of a hypothetical use case, run through the workshop I linked up with a practical example and let me know if this is still unclear?

Comment: Here's a Flask based REST service to render deployment server side similar to how Tiller works... https://gist.github.com/so0k/1e9fe03b71521c26ead07d07078be66d - I still advise you to go for Helm though

Answer (score 10):

After looking into this recently we decided to just go with `sed`. Wrap `kubectl apply` into a small bash script and replace the placeholders before running apply.

We did look into more sophisticated tooling but we only found Helm. However Helm is a complex piece of technology that does way more than just templating. It changes your workflow a lot as you no longer deploy using kubectl and have to have a Helm package repo around to push your packages to. Our assessment was that Helm is not useful for deploying our application and using it for just the templating is overkill.

Comment: helm package repos are not necessary. We moved from Makefiles with `sed` and `kubectl patch deployment ...` to a Flask REST API which rendered Jinja2 templates and used in-cluster service accounts to update Deployments... when we went full Helm we never looked back - save yourself the trouble and give it a try.

Comment: PS: more common is to use sigil instead of sed

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to do this with sed (it is a excerpt from my typical circleci config):

```
replaces="s/{.Namespace}/$CIRCLE_BRANCH/;";
replaces="$replaces s/{.CiBuild}/$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM/; ";
replaces="$replaces s/{.CiCommit}/$CIRCLE_SHA1/; ";
replaces="$replaces s/{.CiUser}/$CIRCLE_USERNAME/; ";

cat ./k8s/app.yaml | sed -e "$replaces" | ./kubectl --kubeconfig=`pwd`/.kube/config apply --namespace=$NAMESPACE -f -
```